# Flutter: ListView disposes widgets when keyboard pops up

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an app with a page that has a ListView.builder().

Each row of the list is a stateful widget (match_chat_row.dart).

When you click on that stateful widget, it's navigating to another stateful widget (chat_screen.dart).

chat_screen.dart has a TextField.

The problem is that last few widgets(match_chat_row.dart) of the ListView are being disposed when the keyboard pops up on one of the first match_chat_row's chat_screen.dart.

I made this simple app to demonstrate it:

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'match_chat_row.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final String _pageName = "Screen";
  List<String> _chats = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _body()
    );
  }

  _body(){
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _chats.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) => _buildRow(_chats[index]),
    );
  }
  
  Widget _buildRow(String chat) {
    return
      Column(
        key: ValueKey<String>('chat-$chat'),
        children: [
          Center(
            child:
            MatchChatRow(
              content: chat,

            ),
          ),
          Divider(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.20), thickness: 0.8, height: 0.0,)
        ],
      );
  }
}
```

match_chat_row.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'chat_screen.dart';
class MatchChatRow extends StatefulWidget {
  final String content;
  const MatchChatRow({required this.content});

  @override
  _MatchChatRowState createState() => _MatchChatRowState();
}

class _MatchChatRowState extends State<MatchChatRow> {
  @override
  void dispose(){
    print("Disposed ROW! ${widget.content}");
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final rowHeight = 100.0;
    final rowPadding = 10.0;

    return
      InkWell(
          onTap: () =>
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => ChatScreen(
                    key: ValueKey(widget.content),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          child:
          Container(
            height: rowHeight,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(rowPadding),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  width: 20.0,
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child:
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(widget.content),
                        Text("_buildSubtitle()"),
                      ],
                    )
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
      );
  }
}
```

chat_screen.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  const ChatScreen({required Key key,}): super(key: key);
  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final TextEditingController _messageController = TextEditingController();
  bool _isComposingMessage = false;
  bool _isChatExist = false;
  bool _isLoading = false;
  bool _isSending = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    print("disposed chat! ${widget.key}");
    super.dispose();
  }

  Container _buildMessageTF() {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8, bottom: 8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border:
          Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.3)),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child:
              TextField(
                minLines: 1,
                maxLines: 4,
                controller: _messageController,
                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                onChanged: (messageText) {
                  setState(() => _isComposingMessage = messageText.isNotEmpty);
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: 'Message...'),
              ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () {
            return Future.value(true);
          },
          child:
          SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("Hi")
              ),
              body:
              SafeArea(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    if (!_isChatExist && !_isLoading) SizedBox.shrink(),
                    _buildMessageTF(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
      );
  }
}
```

And whenever I click on the TextField and the Keyboard pops up the below widgets are being disposed (this is my debug console):

```
I/flutter (23372): Disposed ROW! I
I/flutter (23372): Disposed ROW! J
I/flutter (23372): Disposed ROW! H
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your _body from main

```
  _body(){
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: _chats.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) => _buildRow(_chats[index]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Why is this happening though? What's the reason behind SingleChildScrollView?